# How do I use the Use Navigate from React Router on a button that links to different pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a button that represents shop now that upon click it redirects you on different pages and the card elements have been mapped on external data.
I want this button to navigate to different pages kindly help.

```
   const data =[
    {
        id:"Extensions",
        Title:"Electrical Collections",
        img:"/Assets/Electricals/Extlogo.png",
      

    },
    {
        id:"Phone Accesorries",
        Title:"Phone Accessories",
        img:"/Assets/Phone/phoneacc.png",
    },
    {
        id:"Homeware",
        Title:"Homeware Collections",
        img:"/Assets/Home/home.png",
    

    },
]
 function Home() {
let Navigate =useNavigate();
const handleElectricalPage =  () =>{
    Navigate("/extensionproduct")
   }
<div className='cardContainer'>
          {data.map((item )=>(
              
               <card>
               <div className='imageContainer'>
                   <img src={item.img}  alt='Extension logo'/>
                   </div>
                   <div className='contentsContainer'>
                   <h2>{item.Title}</h2>
                   <div className='iconButtonContainer'>
     
                <button onClick={handleElectricalPage}>Shop Now</button>
                   <ArrowForwardIcon className='arrowIcon'/>
                   </div>
                   </div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. The code you've shared only navigates to a `"/extensionProduct"` path. What have you tried on your own for navigating to different pages? What pages are you trying to navigate to?

Answer (score 1):

Example from the react router https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

```
 navigate("../success", { replace: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an onClick handler (`handleElectricalPage`) dynamically, consider something like this.

```
function Home() {
  let navigate =useNavigate();
  return (
    <div className='cardContainer'>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <card>
          <button 
            onClick={() => navigate(`/externalProduct/${item.id}`)}
          >
           Shop Now
          </button>
        </card>
       )}
   </div>
}
```

You can also use [Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-links) which handles everything by itself

```
<Link to={`/externalProduct/${item.id}`}>
  <button>Shop now</button>
</Link>
```

Comment: its redirecting me to an empty page

Comment: You should update the after path to your desirable path

Answer (score 0):

> App.jsx

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
          <Route path="post/:id" element={<Detail />} />                                        
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Post.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Post(props) {
const navigate = useNavigate()                                                  
      {props.posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div className="post__container" key={post.id}>
            <h4>
              {post.id}&nbsp; {post.title}
            </h4>
            <p>{post.body}</p>                                                                                                                                      
            <button onClick={() => {return navigate(`${post.id}`)}}>Detail</button>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          </div>                                                                                                                                                                                        
        );
      })}      
}
```

> Detail.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router'
 
export default  function Detail (props) { 

    const params = useParams()                          
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState({})              
    
    
    async function getById(id) {                        
        const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id)
        setPosts(response.data)                         
    }

     useEffect(() => {                                  
                                                        
        getById(params.id)                             
     }, [params.id])


return (
<div>
    <h2>Detail page: {params.id}</h2>
    <h4>{posts.title}</h4>
    <h5>{posts.body}</h5>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: When writing an answer, please give an explanation as well rather than just paste the code.